# Show "Scroll Down" Button Only on Overflow (Responsive Design)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, overflow

I'm trying to set up a responsive website whose design adjusts according to the size of the browser it is displayed in (regardless on whether it's on a mobile device or due to resizing on a desktop).

The text I have fits into its div perfectly when displayed full-screen on a desktop but overflows when the browser window shrinks. When that happens - and only then - I want to display a "Scroll Down" Button that immediately shows that there is more content further down the page.

Is there a solution for this that only requires HTML, CSS, and jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for [`.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) property... And compare it with the height of the element that overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Look for [`.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) property... And compare it with the height of the element that overflows.

Below is just an example on how to test it:

```js
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
  var height = $("#test").height();
  var scrollHeight = $("#test")[0].scrollHeight;
  
  if(scrollHeight>height){
    console.log("Need to scroll!");
    // Do something about your button...
  }
});
```

```css
#test{
  height:200px;  /* Just to force it to overflow in this example... */
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim at falli argumentum, rationibus scripserit ei pri, ius ea hendrerit interesset. Nam an iudico omnesque delicatissimi, ut usu suas denique omittantur, ut prima legimus perpetua vis. Quo et aperiam petentium. Affert maiorum eum an, id quo summo quidam.<br>
<br>
Vix et fabulas delenit, rebum commune accusamus an vix. Modo elitr volutpat ex sea, cum partem epicurei at. Ut sea latine perpetua iudicabit, vel movet nullam adipisci ut, cu legere ignota invenire usu. Eam ornatus volutpat sententiae in, et eros lorem duo. Quo ridens possit deleniti cu, no malis offendit mea, ullum soluta volutpat quo an. Eu choro persius posidonium eos.<br>
<br>
Quo amet tale eu. Ne alterum convenire duo, unum nostro probatus eu mei. Ubique nusquam id sit, est posse mandamus salutandi cu. Ea sumo dolores consequuntur sea. Ea mea prodesset gloriatur instructior, te tamquam quaerendum nam, vis eros utinam scaevola eu.<br>
<br>
Vide exerci graeco eum ei, enim graecis alienum usu et. Integre facilisi mnesarchum in mei. Ex mea utinam latine temporibus, periculis reprimique scripserit an eam, ex vix oblique alienum maiestatis. Sed ne veritus maluisset, no mel munere impetus aperiam. Wisi deserunt corrumpit usu ei.<br>
<br>
Dicunt posidonium mea eu, nominavi recusabo sententiae mei ad. Odio ignota per ut, pro menandri definitiones te. Sea ut postea mollis, an habemus persecuti vim. Nam ex reque denique, in eum fugit incorrupte. Sit sale definiebas no, vel mucius vulputate cu, exerci utinam impedit id mea. Vix libris deserunt consequuntur ne, eu sumo dolorem insolens mei. Nam quod unum adversarium eu.
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to attach that to a `resize` event to make it responsive.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb: Sure... Good point! But that's just an example. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work although that may be because of my limited coding skills (I don't know how to attach the code to a `resize` event). However, the code also didn't work for me when I opened it full page after running it - it still showed the "Need to Scroll" text...